# On inequalities concerning a certain function $F$

Tags: functions, inequality, arithmetic-functions

Let $F:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a function that is neither injective nor surjective.

Let $a, b$ be two elements in the domain of $F$.

**QUESTION**

Suppose that the function $F$ satisfies (at the two elements $a$, $b$) the following inequalities:
$$C \leq \frac{1}{2}\cdot\bigg(\frac{F(a)}{b} + \frac{F(b)}{a}\bigg) < \frac{b}{F(a)} + \frac{a}{F(b)}$$
(for some absolute numerical constant $C$) and
$$\frac{1}{2} < \frac{ab}{F(a)F(b)} < \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}.$$

(Note that we can take $C = \sqrt[6]{2}$ by using the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality.)

Does it follow that
$$\frac{b}{F(a)} + \frac{a}{F(b)}$$
is bounded from above?

**MY ATTEMPT**

I tried to rewrite the second set of inequalities as:
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{F(b)}{a} < \frac{b}{F(a)} < \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\cdot\frac{F(b)}{a}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{F(a)}{b} < \frac{a}{F(b)} < \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\cdot\frac{F(a)}{b}$$
but I appear to be going nowhere close to getting an upper bound for
$$\frac{b}{F(a)} + \frac{a}{F(b)}.$$

Comment: Oops, I did not immediately realize that **Question #2** asks essentially the same as **Question #1**, by virtue of the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality.  Editing my question now to remove Question #2.

Comment: The second part of the first inequality $\displaystyle\, \frac{1}{2}\cdot\bigg(\frac{F(a)}{b} + \frac{F(b)}{a}\bigg) < \frac{b}{F(a)} + \frac{a}{F(b)}\,$ is redundant, since it reduces to the first part of the second inequality $\displaystyle\, \frac{1}{2} \lt \frac{ab}{F(a)F(b)}\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $a,b$ and an arbitrary $F$ the obvious upper bound is $\displaystyle\frac{b}{F(a)} + \frac{a}{F(b)}\le a+b\,$.

For arbitrary $a,b,F$ there is no upper bound independent of $\,a,b,F$. Consider for example $\,a=u^2, b=4v^2\,$, $\,F(a)=2v\,$, $\,F(b)=3 u^2 v\,$. The conditions of the problem are satisfied:

- $\displaystyle \frac{F(a)}{b} + \frac{F(b)}{a} = \frac{1}{2v}+3v \ge \sqrt{6}\,$ by AM-GM, so $\displaystyle\,C = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}\,$ works;
- $\displaystyle \frac{ab}{F(a)F(b)} = \frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{3} \in \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\right)\,$.

But $\displaystyle \frac{b}{F(a)} + \frac{a}{F(b)}=2v+\frac{1}{3v}$ can be made arbitrarily large by choosing a large enough $v\,$.